# Remove portion of text using GetElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, replace, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to use the following script to remove ".00" from all prices on a page I'm working on. The ".00" is built in automatically by the WP theme I'm working with.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var str = document.getElementsByClassName("hungry-menu-item-price").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(".00", "");
    document.getElementsByClassName("hungry-menu-item-price").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

The prices are formatted as such:

```
<h4 class="hungry-menu-item-price">$24.00</p>
```

...but it's not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). You must iterate it:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("hungry-menu-item-price");
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; ++i)
  elements[i].textContent = elements[i].textContent.replace(".00", "");
```

```html
<p class="hungry-menu-item-price">$24.00</p>
```

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementsByClassName() function returns a nodeList, not an element

so it must be :

document.getElementsByClassName('hungry-menu-item-price')[0].innerHTML

Comment: Specifically, it returns a `HTMLCollection`, not a `NodeList`.